# Riot Api how to get my puuid using my Summoner ID (the nick name that it shows ingame for me) [League of Legends]

Tags: javascript, riot-games-api

I tried doing methods like :

https://region.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/Executioner?api_key=mykey

I even tried all regions but couldnt find a fitting summoner level to mine so what do I do probably wrong is my Summoner name something different?

my Ingame name is "Executioner" which I tried to use of course and my current level is 53 close to 54

Answer (score 1):

Summoner names are no longer used in League of Legends. They've recently transitioned to Riot IDs, which you should've seen in a popup in the client.

These days, you're required to use the '/riot/account/v1/accounts/by-riot-id/' API, like this: https://europe.api.riotgames.com/riot/account/v1/accounts/by-riot-id/ietsrondsofzo/gamer

Of course, replace "ietsrondsofzo" with your own riot name, and the "gamer" part with your own tagline. You can find these on your profile by clicking the 2 boxes next to your name.

[image]